# Issue on receiving trapv3 on snmptrapd

Tags: snmp, snmptrapd

I have a unix machine where is configured snmptrapd.
The configuration on /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf is the following

```
createUser -e 0x8000000001020304 USRSNMPV3NET SHA "mypwd" AES "mypwd2"
authUser log,execute,net USRSNMPV3NET
# Format logs for collection by Azure Monitor Agent
format2 snmptrap %a %B %y/%m/%l %h:%j:%k %N %W %q %T %W %v \n
```

I configured the process to run with debug, and i can see the trap arriving.
The issue is that i get this error

```
trace: usm_get_user_from_list(): snmpusm.c, 3699:
usm: match on user USRSNMPV3NET
trace: usm_get_user_from_list(): snmpusm.c, 3705:
usm: no match on engineID (80 00 30 44 04 38 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 
32 30 33 30 34 )
trace: usm_get_user_from_list(): snmpusm.c, 3699:
usm: match on user USRSNMPV3NET
trace: usm_get_user_from_list(): snmpusm.c, 3705:
usm: no match on engineID (80 00 30 44 04 38 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 
32 30 33 30 34 )
trace: usm_get_user_from_list(): snmpusm.c, 3699:
usm: match on user USRSNMPV3NET
trace: usm_get_user_from_list(): snmpusm.c, 3705:
usm: no match on engineID (80 00 30 44 04 38 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 30 
32 30 33 30 34 )
trace: usm_process_in_msg(): snmpusm.c, 2561:
usm: Unknown User(USRSNMPV3NET)
trace: snmpv3_parse(): snmp_api.c, 3955:
dumph_recv:     ScopedPDU
trace: _snmp_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4364:
 unknown security name (no such user exists)
trace: _snmp_parse(): snmp_api.c, 4364:
snmp_parse: Parsed SNMPv3 message (secName:USRSNMPV3NET, secLevel:authPriv): USM
 unknown security name (no such user exists)
```

The trap is arriving with the correct engineID

```
trace: usm_parse_security_parameters(): snmpusm.c, 2017:
dumph_recv:     msgAuthoritativeEngineID
dumpx_recv:      04 17 80 00 30 44 04 30 78 38 30 30 30 30 30 30 
30 30 31 30 32 30 33 30 34 
dumpv_recv:        String:      ..0D.0x8000000001020304
trace: usm_parse_security_parameters(): snmpusm.c, 2040:
dumph_recv:     msgAuthoritativeEngineBoots
dumpx_recv:      02 04 63 E6 30 4D 
dumpv_recv:        Integer:     1676030029 (0x63E6304D)
trace: usm_parse_security_parameters(): snmpusm.c, 2064:
dumph_recv:     msgAuthoritativeEngineTime
dumpx_recv:      02 03 1A 4D 18 
dumpv_recv:        Integer:     1723672 (0x1A4D18)
trace: usm_parse_security_parameters(): snmpusm.c, 2092:
dumph_recv:     msgUserName
dumpx_recv:      04 0C 55 53 52 53 4E 4D 50 56 33 4E 45 54 
dumpv_recv:        String:      USRSNMPV3NET
trace: usm_parse_security_parameters(): snmpusm.c, 2135:
dumph_recv:     msgAuthenticationParameters
dumpx_recv:      04 0C 94 0D CE 2D 62 3E 63 CF 69 03 E6 FE 
dumpv_recv:        String:      .^M.-b>c.i...
trace: usm_parse_security_parameters(): snmpusm.c, 2164:
```

I've tried to change sender EngineID and configuration, change the user, change the engine id type of the sender from TEXT to HEX, but nothing worked.

Comment: Since you are following the official guide, https://net-snmp.sourceforge.io/wiki/index.php/TUT:Configuring_snmptrapd_to_receive_SNMPv3_notifications what happens if you generate the TRAP using `snmptrap`? Does `snmptrapd` receive it properly?